# Does the way we bring images to PS change the resolution?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, image-quality

I noticed sharpness of image is different depends on how we bring it to photoshop. For e.g. via import, drag and drop, placed, open or load to PS. Is it just me or it is how it supposed to be?

Comment: Yea thats how its supposed to be. After all you may want to import pixels as 1:1 or you may want to import physical size as 1:1

Comment: When you place files they might be scaled to fit the opened image: in this case sharpness might depend on your resize settings. Maybe you'd want to upload some examples to illustrate your question.

Comment: Yes, it can. There many ways to get images into Photoshop. What do you want to happen when you import/place?  If you don't want the resolution to change, open the file directly, select all, copy and paste into another image.  Placing an image can also result in a linked image file/smart object, depending on your settings. Also placing an image can resize it to fit, again depends on your settings in preferences.